# Rotate TIF/JPG images without losing metadata: EXIF and Color profile

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, colors

I have working code to rotate the image. But I have a requirement to preserve meta data, particularly color profile information.

Comment: What have you tried? There are EXIF libraries that read and write the data so you could use one of those.

Comment: I haven't tried yet. I am trying to gather information before doing so, so as to avoid reinventing the wheel. Do you know of any specific library that can do this (rotate while preserving color profile), in a high level fashion?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void Rotate(string fileName,RotateFlipType rft, string targetMimeType)
    {
        ImageCodecInfo imageCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Single(i => i.MimeType == targetMimeType);

        EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParams.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);

        using( Image im = Image.FromFile(fileName, true))
        {
            im.RotateFlip(rft);
            im.Save("rotated_"+fileName, imageCodecInfo, encoderParams);
        }
    }
```

How does that look?